# How well is the thinkpad internal microphone supported?(x230)

Tags: pulseaudio, thinkpad, microphone

Specs say it's an internal digital stereo microphone.
Windows does have an option to switch between conference and singleuser mode, like most voice recorders with stereo mics.

Is this Option hardware or software based? 
What kind of signal does ubuntu receive from the stereomic? Mono or stereo?
Is it possible to use this conference/singleuser option?
It's a really nice feature and it would be a tragedy if ubuntu wouldnt support it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's supported, it should be an input mode selectable in `pavucontrol` (both package to install and the command to run) in the tab "Input Devices" or "Configuration". Check that out using the most recent version of Ubuntu.

Example screen:

[image]

Alternatively, find more of these 'switches' in `alsamixer` (run in the terminal).

Comment: yes it shows stereo-mic, but how do i implement filtering? i mean thats why stereomics are used to filter sound. for example by cuting phasedistance...

Comment: I don't have knowledge of the implementation on your machine. If it's some hardware thingy, it might be supported by the  driver and available as a switch in `alsamixer` - see the updated answer.